# React useEffect gets data from database but not in time to be used in the component

Tags: reactjs

I am using useEffect to get data from an api.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
          try {
              const response = await fetch(
                  `/api/posts/getCats`
              );
              const cats = await response.json();
              console.log(cats);
          } catch (e) {
              console.error(e);
          }
      };
      fetchData();
  }, []);
```

The problem is when I try to use it in the return, its value is undefined.

```
 {cats.map((data) => {
```

`cats` has value when I console.log it.

I cannot use componentDidMount because all my code is functional components.

**Edit:** I updated the code as per answers below but still get
`TypeError: cats.map is not a function`
All answers below actually make sense but I am not sure why its not working.

```
export default function Posts() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/posts/getCats`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setCats)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  
  return (
      <div>
        {cats?.map((data) => {
            <h4>{data.main}</h4>
        })}
        </div>
      )      
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't change immediately. but you can add an if statement to check the length of cats. or simply `{cats?.map((data) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because React renders your screen before finishing to get response from API. When you render screen, variable *cats* doesn't have values. You can run useEffect after each rendering. You can rerender by changing state from useEffect (This technique is often used). Do not forget to add [] or [cats] as a dependency of useEffect (second params) otherwise you will get infinite loop.

Below code works even when cats === [] or some array.

```
export default () => {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `/api/posts/getCats`
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        setCats(result)
      } catch (e) {
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {cats.map(cat => <div>cat</div>)}
    </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- call `setCats` when the response comes back (right now, you're just logging it)
- `.map` only once `cats` has been populated:

```
const [cats, setCats] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`/api/posts/getCats`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => setCats(result.cats))
    .catch(console.error);
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {cats?.map((data) => {
      // ...
```

Comment: This doesn't rerender even when you get cats. (This comment is posted before edit)

Comment: Thanks but what is `setData`? Do you mean `setCats`? I still get `TypeError: cats.map is not a function`

Comment: @Kal The variable names confused me, fixed. Maybe call the state variable `cats` and the mapped item `cat` instead? Make sure you're using `cats?.map`, not `cats.map`, as in the answer

Comment: Please see my updated question with the updated code. Still same error :(

Comment: @Kal Sounds like your API does not return an array then. Figure out what it returns so you can figure out how to iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks - I added a screenshot showing its an array. But you are right, let me make sure it can be iterated.

Comment: @Kal It's not an array, it's an object. You have to access its `cats` property to get to the array. `.then(result => setCats(result.cats))`

Comment: My bad. I was playing with it and added wrong screenshot. I added added pic of the array. Let me try to iterate over this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason I kept getting the same error. I dont know the difference but Naoki Watanabe's answer worked. There must be something wrong. Upvoted though!

Answer (score 1):

You have to map the cats data into state.

```
const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
          try {
              const response = await fetch(
                  `/api/posts/getCats`
              );
              const data = await response.json();
              setCats(data);
          } catch (e) {
              console.error(e);
          }
      };
      fetchData();
  }, []);
```